# how to maintain different counter in same table in ralis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

i created `invoice` model which has attributes `invoice_type` which takes value like 1 for tax_invoice and 2 for proforma_invoice. now i want to maintain separate unique increment counter in same table . how can i do this in rails 5 application.

my current model code looks like this:

```
 def set_invoice_number
   self.update_attribute(:invoice_number, 'abc/2020-21/' + id.to_s)
 end
```

Example :
for type 1 invoice i want to maintain counter 1,2,3.... based on previous created type 1 invoice created.

for type 2 invoice i want to maintain counter 1,2,3.... based on previous created type 2 invoice created.

i want to append id in format like `'abc/2020-21/' + id.to_s` and save to invoice table in invoice_number attribute.

Comment: Can you give example for the expected counters?

Comment: @Salil sure please check hope it's clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id is generated by the primary key sequence of the underlying database table. Its a counter and not a count of the rows in the table. This is a really important thing to remember as using a count of the *current rows* can lead to duplicate numbers if a row is ever deleted!

Some databases like postgres let you define custom sequences which basically just a table with a counter on it:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE tax_invoice_serial START 1;
CREATE SEQUENCE proforma_invoice_serial START 1;
```

You would then assign the invoice_number by getting the next value from the database sequence:

```
self.update("invoice_number = CONCAT('abc/2020-21/', nextval('tax_invoice_serial'))")
```

To select the sequence dynamically use a case statement:

```
self.update(
  <<~SQL 
    name = (
      CASE 
        WHEN invoice_type = 1 THEN CONCAT('abc/2020-21/', nextval('tax_invoice_serial'));
        WHEN invoice_type = 2 THEN CONCAT('abc/2020-21/', nextval('proforma_invoice_serial'));
      END
    )
  SQL
})
```

As the whole sequence generation occurs in the database its not prone to race conditions like a Ruby based solution would be. Of course you could also use a [database trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-createtrigger.html) to handle this instead of model callbacks.

On other db's like MySQL and SQLite that just have AUTO_INCREMENT I would consider other alternatives like splitting this into two seperate tables.

See:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-createsequence.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF01314
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: i am using sqlite in development and postgres in production, how can i make this logic work in both env.

Comment: Stop using sqlite in development instead - and use the same database in dev/test/production. https://12factor.net/dev-prod-parity

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of depending on the `id`, you should create a new running number in your database.

Then when saving you should take the previous `number` of the invoice type.

```
def set_invoice_number
  next_invoice_number = Invoice.where(invoice_type: 1).maximum(:number).to_i + 1
  
  self.update_attributes(
   invoice_number: 'abc/2020-21/' + next_invoice_number.to_s,
   number: next_invoice_number
  )
end
```

The `to_i` handles the case where there are no previous numbers.

Comment: should i create ```number``` column in ```invoice``` table

Comment: Yes and you'll also query the number by the current `invoice_type`.